# When running Stylecop in Sonar, how do I make it analyze projects identified as test projects?

Tags: c#, testing, sonarqube, stylecop

Ok, so let's assume that I want to live according to the rule, treat your test code as carefully as your production code. How do I make Sonar and Stylecop analyze my test projects?

I've basically written this in my sonar-project.properties file:

```
#Core C# Settings 
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=SomeSolution.sln 
sonar.dotnet.excludeGeneratedCode=true
sonar.dotnet.version=4.0
sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*.Tests

#StyleCop
sonar.stylecop.mode=
```

Reading the sonar build log I see that all projects except the tests (i.e. SomeTestProject.Tests) project are analyzed by Stylecop.

How can I make sonar+stylecop analyze my Tests project as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this is unsupported in Sonar 3.3+C# plugin 2.0. To be fixed in 2.1
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARDOTNT-224?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel