# Can I analyze C# test projects in Sonar using the Visual Studio Analysis Bootstrapper?

Tags: c#, testing, sonarqube

I am using **SonarQube 5.0**, together with the **C# plugin (3.3)**, **StyleCop Plugin (1.1)** and **Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects Plugin (1.2)**.

On the [documentation page for the Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Bootstrapper+for+Visual+Studio+Projects+Plugin), it is stated that **unit test code will not be analyzed**. But I would like to treat the test code with the same care we treat production code.

I have found this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397622/when-running-stylecop-in-sonar-how-do-i-make-it-analyze-projects-identified-as), where it says that this is not supported, but I think that this might have changed from 2012.

I have also found this closed [SonarQube task](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCS-369), which states that FxCop and StyleCop should analyze unit tests, but duplication detection does not work.

My question is:

**Can I analyze test code** (FxCop, StyleCop, complexity, duplication)  using the Visual Studio Bootstrapper. If not, can I do it if I don't use the bootstrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyzing test code is still not supported.

However, you can tell Visual Studio Bootstrapper plugin to consider all code as production code, by setting `sonar.visualstudio.testProjectPattern` to not match anything - but this is a workaround. All the code will then be analyzed in the exact same way.

Comment: I think I prefer this approach instead of completely ignoring test code. Thanks!